# /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: services, shared-library, mariadb

```
p2@P2:~$sudo systemctl restart mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
p2@P2:~$sudo systemctl status mariadb
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.31 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-08-13 15:13:46 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 313918 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 313919 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 313921 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSRE>
    Process: 313968 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 313968 (code=exited, status=127)

srp 13 15:13:46 P2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.31 database server...
srp 13 15:13:46 P2 mysqld[313968]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
srp 13 15:13:46 P2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
srp 13 15:13:46 P2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
srp 13 15:13:46 P2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.
```

**srp 13 15:13:46 P2 mysqld[313968]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Okay, so mariaDB can't find the liblz4-1 library. However:

Package liblz4-1 is installed and up to date. liblz4.so.1 is installed at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1

If we run mariaDB by itself:

```
p2@P2:~$ /usr/sbin/mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But if we run ldd on mariaDB to find the required libraries:

```
p2@P2:~$ ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe322c0000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fa0406cd000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007fa0406c2000)
    libaio.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007fa0406bd000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa0406a1000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa04062e000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fa0405f3000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fa040542000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa04053c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa04035a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa04020b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa0401e8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa03fff6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa03ffd9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa03ffce000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fa03ffa5000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fa03fe87000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa0423ec000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fa03fe64000)
```

ldd **can** find the library! (If it couldn't it would output liblz4.so.1 => not found)

Okay, so what causes this error and how do I get mariaDB to run?

Additional note: Some very deep diving on the internet revealed that this issue **may** be due to a missing/broken [library loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system). However, I suspect the advice given is outdated, since their issues are caused my multiple architectures, and the packages in my system are 64-bit. Also, the loaders they are referring to don't exist on my distribution.

Also, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

edit: library checksums

```
find / -name "liblz4.so*" -type f 2> /dev/null | xargs sha256sum
536ab2f5d4448fd1ff62d43b99ece092ec7824b083af7c7007bb0889353d2777  /snap/snap-store/542/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
536ab2f5d4448fd1ff62d43b99ece092ec7824b083af7c7007bb0889353d2777  /snap/snap-store/547/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
c619a6d991c87ec2967b2b0c417ae5a9b86a76f11396ff5492947b4f637369db  /snap/snapd/12704/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
c619a6d991c87ec2967b2b0c417ae5a9b86a76f11396ff5492947b4f637369db  /snap/snapd/12398/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
c619a6d991c87ec2967b2b0c417ae5a9b86a76f11396ff5492947b4f637369db  /snap/core/11420/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
c619a6d991c87ec2967b2b0c417ae5a9b86a76f11396ff5492947b4f637369db  /snap/core/11316/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
536ab2f5d4448fd1ff62d43b99ece092ec7824b083af7c7007bb0889353d2777  /snap/core18/2128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
536ab2f5d4448fd1ff62d43b99ece092ec7824b083af7c7007bb0889353d2777  /snap/core18/2074/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.7.1
d6574e34006e27cfb5d00dc75018cc06832d0bbc9e1b35316b9c03148355f0a0  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.2
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1` show? it should be a symbolic link. Is it broken?

Comment: It shows that it's a symlink to liblz4.so.1.9.2 in the same directory. I don't see any errors there.

Comment: Please run `find / -name "liblz4.so*" -type f | xargs sha256sum` and add result to the question body. On fresh 20.04 LTS VM with all updates I have `d6574e34006e27cfb5d00dc75018cc06832d0bbc9e1b35316b9c03148355f0a0  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.2` .

Comment: I've edited my post, but the checksum is the same as the one you posted. I think if the library was corrupted, it wouldn't give a  "No such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 1):

It's AppArmor, annoyingly it says "No such file or directory". This answer fixed it for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Server): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423057/539198

> This worked for me :-
>
> `sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/`
>
> `sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
>
> It also disables the AppArmor for MySQL on the system though.
>
> [Got from this issue](https://github.com/aptalca/docker-zoneminder/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

To remove mariadb from app armor, this is what worked for me

To resolve look for mysqld on the app armor status output:

```
$ sudo aa-status
```

Then follow the steps below to remove mysqld from the app armor:

```
$ echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" | sudo tee /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ sudo apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```